# Gradle syncs with ButterKnife

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, butterknife

I added `ButterKnife` to my android project. Like the [documentation](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) says, i added this dependencies to the `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
}
```

And i'm getting this error when `gradle` syncs:

```
Error:Could not download rxjava.jar (io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.3): No cached version available for offline mode
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: you should turn off offline gradle build in android studio gradle settings.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it. Please, consider post it as an answer so i can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **Turn Off** the offline gradle build in android studio's gradle settings.

Then it will take the updated library from repo.